# Prove for every Riemann mid sum of $f(x)=x$ of $[0,b]$ is the integral $\int_{0}^{b}f(x)dx$?

Tags: riemann-sum

I found that Riemann mid sum for arbitrary partition is $S(P, f)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i^2-x_{i-1}^2)=\dfrac{b^2}{2}$, and now I have to show that Riemann sum approaches this value, i.e. chosen points and partition doesn't affect as long norm $|P|$ is small enough.

Comment: Not every Riemann sum of $f(x)=x$ on $[0,b]$ is equal to $\frac12b^2$.

Comment: @Did I meant for middle sum, or is it wrong too?

Comment: It's not true for ever riemann sum. Maybe the best that you can do is define some sequence of subintervals $(I_n)$ so that  for the lengths$\mathcal{L}(I_n)$,  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathcal{L}(I_n) \to 0$ . In this case, all but finitely many of the corresponding Riemann sums will be within $\epsilon$ of $\frac{1}{2}b^2$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: That might on the other hand, be a totally useless endeavor. Just pick a partition so that when the mesh is sufficiently small, the riemann sum over that partition will be within $\epsilon$ of $b^2/2$.

Comment: Every sum using the middle points to evaluate the function is equal to $\frac12b^2$, yes. If this is what you have in mind, this should be clearly stated in the question.

Comment: @LawNeutral The second half of the question doesn't seem to agree with the first paragraph. Perhaps it would help to supply your definition of "integral" and "Riemann Sum." It is certainly not true that every Riemann sum evaluates to $\frac{1}{2}b^2$.

Comment: $Andres Mejia, I edited the question, but English is not my native language so I may have some trouble.

Comment: I think the real problem is the term "for every"

Comment: Damn. I forgot to edit the title too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, IF you found that for every partition, the corresponding riemann sum equals $\frac {b^2}2$, then for any $\delta>0$ we already have that

$$
|P|<\delta \implies  0=|S(P,f)-I|<\varepsilon
$$

Since the consequent is always true.

---

Also, just a remark: If it wasn't the case that for every riemann sum, the 'limit' (i.e, your $I$ here), the integral $\int_0^b f$ would not exist, as, per definition, the symbol $\int_0^b f $ is defined to be $I$ when this is equal for each and every Riemann sum (else, we say $f$ is not integrable over $[0,b]$, and it would make no sense to talk about $f$'s integral).

Comment: What? Riemann integrability is **not** defined as the fact that every Riemann sum is equal to the same value (if it was, nearly only the constant functions would be integrable). Please avoid comforting the OP in this false belief.

Comment: @Did Whoops, that may have been terrible wording there, I meant the $I$'s should be the same for each Riemann sum. (Actually, re-reading my answer, I believe I was clear...)

Comment: I actually also think this is fairly clear, it doesn't seem to be a "false comfort."

Comment: @AndresMejia Please be constructive: the exercise is false as stated, so, either we help the OP correct it or we mislead them.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I thought you were suggesting that the current answer had the same problem as the way the question was asked.

Comment: I still don't see your point, Did, I believe you were referring to my "Remark" paragraph, is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: @Yo Really? Quotes: "I meant for middle sum". "Every sum using the middle points to evaluate the function is equal to $\frac12b^2$, yes. If this is what you have in mind, this should be clearly stated in the question." The point seems pretty clearly stated to me.